# PowerShell mask Get-ItemPropertyValue one-liner in batch file

Tags: powershell, batch-file, one-liner

I use PowerShell one-liners in several batch scripts, but seem failing to escape the following one correctly:

```
if not defined LANGUAGE (
for /f "usebackq" %%v in (`PowerShell.exe -NoProfile -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -Command "(Get-ItemPropertyValue -Path 'HKCU:Control Panel\International\' -Name 'LocaleName').Split('-')[0]"`) do set LANGUAGE=%%v
)
```

I verified that it is this line that fails in my batch file. The idea behind the code is to read the value from the registry and assign the first part before the hyphen to an environment variable. So if the registry value is "de-DE", LANGUAGE shall have the value of "de".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I cannot reproduce an issue with the code you've provided.

I would however suggest you consider other approaches - compare these examples and note which executes the fastest

```bat
@Echo off

 Setlocal

 For /f "delims=" %%v in ('where /r "%Windir%\SysWOW64\WindowsPowerShell" powershell.exe')Do Set "powershell=%%v -nologo -noprofile"

 Echo(%TIME%
 For /f "usebackq" %%v in (`PowerShell.exe -NoProfile -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -Command "(Get-ItemPropertyValue -Path 'HKCU:Control Panel\International\' -Name 'LocaleName').Split('-')[0]"`) do set "LANGUAGE=%%v"
 Set LANG
 Echo(%TIME%

 For /f "usebackq tokens=1 Delims=-" %%G in (`
  %powershell% -c "Get-ItemPropertyValue -Path 'HKCU:Control Panel\International\' -Name 'LocaleName'"
 `)Do Set "LANGUAGE=%%G"
 Set LANG
 Echo(%TIME%

 For /f "Skip=1 tokens=3 Delims=- " %%G in ('reg query "HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Control Panel\International" /v localename')Do Set "LANGUAGE=%%G"
 Set LANG
 Echo(%TIME%

 Endlocal
Goto:Eof
```